# Create webform element

Tags: webforms

I'm currently trying to create a clone of the webform element 'text field' with a new name.  This is simply so that the new element can be styled independently.

(I know I could use template/theme suggestions - or use the module themable_forms - but we have a specific use case.  The site editor may want to add the same element to other forms.  So - for example - I clone the text field element to first_name element - and the front-end guy can then theme the first_name element with a relevant twig template - and if that element is used on other forms then it will pick up that (first name) template).

The difficulty I have is in creating the new webform element.  Drupal's console generate:plugin:skeleton produces a Plugin class which does not work - for one thing the dependencies listed in the annotation for the class is the string 'array' (removing the dependency line fixes that) - but something else is causing the 'insert element' pop-up box to fail to load.

I'm looking to use the example webform element module - but wondered if anyone had a successful walk-through for creating a new webform element from scratch?

Comment: There is the first time I have heard of anyone trying to use Drupal console to generate a Form/Render Element and/or a Webform Element. There are webform element examples included within the Webform module. @see https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/modules

Comment: @jrockowitz - thanks again
Are there any walkthroughs for using the webform_example_element module to create a new webform element.  I've tried copying the

webform_example_element/src/Element/WebformExampleElement.php to 
mymodule/src/Element/WebformExampleElement.php 

and copying
webform_example_element/src/Plugin/WebformElement/WebformExampleElement.php
to
mymodule/src/Plugin/WebformElement/WebformExampleElement.php

but this gives me an error of:
'Drupal\mymodule\Element\WebformExampleElement' does not exist
in Drupal\Component\Plugin\Factory\DefaultFactory::getPluginClass()

Comment: I presume I don't need to copy 

config/install/webform.webform.webform_example_element.yml

as that is only going to create an example form - which I don't need - I only want a new element.

Comment: @jrockowitz  And if I move 
mymodule/src/Element/WebformExampleElement.php
to
mymodule/Element/WebformExampleElement.php

Error is:

Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginException: Plugin (webform_example_element) instance class "Drupal\qf_plugins\Plugin\WebformElement\WebformExampleElement" does not exist. in Drupal\Component\Plugin\Factory\DefaultFactory::getPluginClass() (line 97 of /home/kbailey/websites/kb-dev-1/code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Factory/DefaultFactory.php).

which is difficult to fix because the class file is there.  Something to do with autoloading?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question - this is how to use the webform element example module (which is a submodule of webform) to create your own webform element.

Copy

```
webform_example_element/src/Element/WebformExampleElement.php
```

to

```
mymodule/src/Element/WebformExampleElement.php
```

and copy

```
webform_example_element/src/Plugin/WebformElement/WebformExampleElement.php
```

to

```
mymodule/src/Plugin/WebformElement/WebformExampleElement.php
```

Then in both of those files change the namespace line from:

```
namespace Drupal\webform_example_element\Plugin\WebformElement;
```

to

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\WebformElement;
```

Clear caches and this example element should now appear in the element list to be added to a form.

NB - you don't need to copy webform_example_element/config/install/webform.webform.webform_example_element.yml 
as this is used to create the an example form to display the example element.
NB - the class Element/WebformExampleElement.php is needed as this is the basis of the new webform element.

Comment: I've not checked the form submission yet - this will be done in the next couple of days.